# Consume Rest Api with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, json, sql-server-2016

I try to consume a `Rest API (JSON export)` with `SSIS`. Since it seems that a `REST source` is not supported by `SSIS` I was looking for a solution but could only find the [SSIS JSON Source](http://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/ssis-json-file-source/).

Is there a non proprietary solution or is this feature even supported by the new SQL Server 2016?
I checked that as well could not find anything specific though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [script component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx) which is supported in 2016 and previous versions.

Make sure that when you add the component you select ["source" as the type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx) and not destination or transformation.

Then you add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions.dll` to the task and write some code to consume the webservice.

[This blog post](http://dennysjymbo.blogspot.be/2013/05/using-json-feed-as-data-source-in-ssis.html) looks like it documents the process nicely, but the key is that you consume the json and override the `CreateNewOutputRows` method to send whatever you are receiving to the task's output. The output can be connected to any SSIS component accepting a data flow input.

If you insist on using a source component there is [JSONSource](https://jsonsource.codeplex.com/) on codeplex but they don't support SQL 2016 yet, but I don't think it's necessary to add a JSON component if you are only consuming a single service and it's not really complicated to implement yourself.